# Can't find the package for XInput2.h header file on nixos

Tags: go, nix, xorg, nixos

I have been trying to build some go projects that use X11 libraries and I have been getting an error like this when trying to build https://github.com/npmaile/PapeChanger/.

```
45 | #include <X11/extensions/Xinerama.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Whenever this happens I usually just lookup in nix-pkgs for the package usually named "xorg.lib<header_file_name>" or in this case the package "xorg.libXinerama".
This usually works fine, but in the last couple projects I have been coming across this error.

```
48 | #include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

When trying to lookup this library I just can't seem to find the package for it anywhere.

I tried xorg.xinput and found it was a program rather than a library. I tried to look high and low in the nix-pkgs website to find the library and came up empty. As a sanity check, I did some searching to see if it was a thing and found [this page in the xorg docs](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/inputproto/XI2proto.txt) as well as [this fedora wiki page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/XI2#Current_status) about the library.

What I am looking for is what Xinput2 is packaged under. It seems like a rather core component so I can't imagine it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file comes from the "dev" output of the `xorg.libXi` derivation in nixpkgs.  Here are some commands I ran in a checkout of the nixpkgs repository to confirm that:

```
$ nix-build -A xorg.libXi.dev
/nix/store/qrs00hnv9frpk49rbp6dir3vqw0my8j7-libXi-1.8-dev
$ ls result-dev/include/X11/extensions
XInput2.h  XInput.h
```

Comment: Thanks! I am also curious of how you figured that out. Did you happen to know that, Did you search for it like I did on the nix-pkgs website, or do you have some magical method?

Comment: In general I would recommend using the [Debian package contents search](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=XInput2.h) or something similar.
In this case though, I have a project named [nixcrpkgs](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/nixcrpkgs) which includes a package I named `libxall`, which is a collection of cross-compiled X libraries.  So I looked for XInput2.h in `libxall` and used `realpath` to see which library it came from.

Comment: You can use `nix-locate` for finding binaries or libraries like this, for example `nix-locate XInput2.h` would have shown you a result with `xorg.libXi.dev`.